# NextFlow: how to use inputStream with DSL2

Tags: java-stream, workflow, nextflow

Using NextFlow (DSL=2), I would like to use each line of a file as a streaming input of my workflow.

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

process bar {
    input: val data
    output: val result
    exec:
    result = data.toUpperCase()
}

workflow {
    myFile = file('input_test.txt')
    myReader = myFile.newReader()
    myFile.withInputStream {
        String line
        while( line = myReader.readLine() ) {
            channel.from(line) | bar | view
        }
    }
}
```

I face the problem that I can only use the "bar" process once:
`Process 'bar' has been already used -- If you need to reuse the same component include it with a different name or include in a different workflow context`

I have also tried to create a subworkflow that takes the channel from line and call bar.

Is there a way to use streamed data as an input using Nextflow?

Note: my final goal is not just to apply an upper case function. I would like to link several complex processes on the data stream.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code looks like an anti-pattern - it will try to create a new channel for each line in your input file. Instead, have a look at the [splitting operators](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#splitting-operators), especially the [splitText operator](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#splittext):

```
workflow {
    Channel.fromPath('input_test.txt')
        | splitText { it.trim() } \
        | bar \
        | view()
}
```

If the above doesn't help, please describe exactly what you want to do with each line in your input file.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Yes the code I have produced so far does not produce the expected behavior.
I would like to use a non-finite set of elements as an input and stream it to the workflow through a channel, without having to "launch" a new run of the workflow for each new line. I was thinking of "feeding" a channel but I also struggled to without the `bind` or "<<" operators that were deprecated with DSL2.
Is it more clear?

Comment: Sorry @Nine, I'm not sure I'm following. From what I understand, the splitText op should fulfil those requirements. The process 'bar' could be a (named) workflow for example. Also, the channel [create](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#create) method has been deprecated with DSL2.